# Mongodb update document through ruby not working

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I want to update documents in MongoDB via Ruby code. I have document ids of documents I want to update only a specific field. I tried the following code.

```
collection.update({"_id".to_s => doc_id},{"$set"=> {"selected" => "false"}})
```

and also

```
collection.update({"_id".to_s => doc_id},{"selected" => "false"})
```

Both commands execute without any error but the database remains unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Tutorial), the way to update a document are

```
collection.update({"_id" => id}, doc)
```

or

```
collection.update({"_id" => id}, {"$set" => {"name" => "MongoDB Ruby"}})
```

The ID is expected to be a valid id. I'm not sure if a string is accepted, in case make sure to convert it to a `BSON::ObjectId`.

```
collection.update({"_id" => BSON::ObjectId.from_string(doc_id) }, {"$set" => {"selected" => "false" }})
```

Make sure to check the command returns `true`.

Also note that if you are using a driver version < 1.8, you should be using `:safe => true`.

> The driver will send a getlasterror command after every write to ensure that the write succeeded by default. Prior to version 1.8 of the driver, writes were not acknowledged by default and it was necessary to explicitly specify the option ':safe => true' for write confirmation. This is no longer the case.

Comment: thanks ..converting the string doc_id to bson object fixed it